# Why does the equality stand, if $A,B$ have no common elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$x \in \mathcal{P}A \cup \mathcal{P} B \rightarrow x \in \mathcal{P}A \lor x \in \mathcal{P}B \rightarrow x \subset A \lor x \subset B \rightarrow x \subset A \cup B \rightarrow x \in \mathcal{P} (A \cup B)$$

So, $\mathcal{P}A \cup \mathcal{P}B \subset P(A \cup B) $.

The equality stands, if $A \cap B=\varnothing$.

Could you explain me why the equality stands, if $A,B$ have no common elements?

Answer (score 2):

That's not true. Try $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{2\}$.

Comment: Mike A ok.. But, then how can I find a condition that must be satisfied, so that $\mathcal{P}A \cup \mathcal{P}B=P(A \cup B)$ ?

Comment: If $A\subset B$, or $B\subset A$.

Answer (score 0):

If $b\in B-A$ and $a\in A-B$ then $\{a,b\}\in P(A\cup B)$ but $\{a,b\}\notin P(A)\cup P(B)$.

That is

$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)\cup P(B)\implies A\subset B\vee B\subset A$$

The reciprocal is also true, for if for instance $B\subset A$ then $P(B)\subset P(A)$ and therefore, $P(A\cup B)=P(A)=P(B)\cup P(A)$.